# How does import.io do its magic?

Tags: web-scraping, import.io

Can anyone give a rough outline of how import.io might do what it does?

For example try

```
https://magic.import.io/?site=http:%2F%2Fwww.zara.com%2Fuk%2F
```

It finds the navigation and submenus perfectly.

How can a scraper abstract to the level of working with any website fed to it like this? Not relying on a specific websites DOM structure or class names.

I know it's closed source, and I'm obviously just asking at a broad level here...what are our best guesses?

Comment: The menu has classes, ids, elements containing "menu", so that's one possibility. Also a lot of sites use content management systems (wordpress, opencart, virtuemart) that have similar structure so that's also one possibility. Also, for the most popular sites they maybe have written the rules manually in order to give good results.

Comment: It could render elements using a full-featured JS-based browser (like Phantom.JS) and then measure the distances of elements things to see how they are related. For example, the shop that sells chairs would group an image, a title, a description and a price close together, even if the HTML is not semantic or JS is heavily involved (that would normally make it hard to parse).